# Работают ли уведомления со странными именами?

Tags: поддержка, уведомления, идентификатор-участника

Вот есть [вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1163346/178988). Я отвечая на комментарий явно обратился к пользователю. Поскольку сейчас его комментарий единственный, то уведомление он всё равно получит. Но вообще, автодополнение после `@` автоматически предложило имя с пробельными символами по краям. Нормально ли это? Будут ли приходить уведомления такому пользователю в дальнейшем, если я буду к нему обращаться?

[image: скриншот]

Имя пользователя: `ᅠhᅠ` (или в кодах `\u1160\u0068\u1160`).

Символ [называется](https://unicode-table.com/ru/1160/) *Хангыль чунсон filler,* что лично мне ни о чём не говорит, но визуально он смотрится как пробельный.

Comment: «... со странными именами» Кто бы говорил :)

Comment: Discovery requires experimentation. Поменял свой ник, попробуйте пропинговать.

Comment: Вряд ли этот символ обрабатывается как пробельный, учитывая что он не входит в категорию [Zs](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm)

Comment: @ᅠdefaultlocaleᅠping

Comment: @dIm0n Не работает

Comment: @ᅠdefaultlocaleᅠ - автоподстановка ника, пробел, дефис.

Comment: @defaultlocale - руками убрал края.

Comment: @default - ещё и сократил. Пришло что-то из этого?

Comment: @Qwertiy пришло первое "автоподстановка ника, пробел, тире"

Comment: @dIm0n, ты накосячил - после ника нет пробела, получается, что ping - часть ника.

Comment: @ᅠdefaultlocaleᅠ, а если с запятой?

Comment: @Qwertiy с запятой тоже пришло

Comment: @ᅠdefaultlocaleᅠ, отлично, значит работает. Переименовать тебя обратно?

Comment: @ᅠdefaultlocale, ещё вот так хочу попробовать - по идее должно работать?

Comment: @Qwertiy похоже, что действительно не поставил свой пробел, извиняюсь

Comment: @Qwertiy тоже работает, получается главное правильный префикс

Comment: @Qwertiy о, кстати да, переименуй если не сложно, а то я уже было смирился 30 дней ждать.

Comment: @ᅠdef, до 3 или 4 символов (не помню точно) можно сокращать, если уникальность сохраняется.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, так тоже работает.

Comment: @defaultlocale, переименовал только для этого сайта - верно?

Comment: @Qwertiy все правильно, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Провели эксперимент - работает, если не забывать после символа, являющегося частью ника, ставить разделитель (например, пробел или запятую).

Символ в начале имени удалять нельзя - без него уведомление не придёт, символ в конце - в соответствии со стандартными правилами сокращения - если есть минимальная длина и пользователь уникален. В случае с пользователем из вопроса скорее всего будет нельзя, поскольку 2 символа - это слишком мало.